# Return Receipt NOT working when email is sent from Lotus Notes Mail-database to Gmail using Lotus Script

Tags: gmail, lotusscript, lotus

I am sending emails from Lotus notes action using agent (maildoc.ReturnReceipt = "1") to gmail expecting Return receipt but I am not receiving any return receipt message when mail is opened in gmail. Could you please let me know if there is any attribute I need to add my lotus script agent to receive the return receipt from gmail?

Comment: Please, show your code - add it to your question.

Answer (score 1):

Return receipts on GMAIL aren't available for all GMAIL Accounts. Probably only on GMAIL for business, and it the option should be enabled on the recipient's account.